Is it possible to water jet or cut/break through an existing underground corrugated drain pipe+foam?
My gutter downspouts connect to an underground corrugated drain pipe which passes underneath a concrete sidewalk. The previous owner had the sidewalk poly-jacked which resulted in the drain pipe being filled with foam (I assume a break in the drain pipe would have led to the settling sidewalk) and no longer drains water properly.
I've not been able to clear the foam from the pipe so far, so I plan on putting in a new drain pipe. If possible, I would like to repair this without removing/replacing concrete. Using this method of a small trench, water, and a hammer appears to be suitable for my situation. I'm curious if this technique will get fouled up by the existing pipe/foam though if I can't stay clear of it.
Is it possible to water jet through, or otherwise cut/break through, an existing underground corrugated drain pipe+foam combination?

Get a contractor with the kit to give you a price, if not they will tell you it cannot be done.

@SolarMike, as a former contractor with scruples I bristle at any suggestion of exploitation with no intent to hire. That's just sleazy, and it may be legally considered theft of services. Maybe that's not what you meant, but it comes up a lot here.

I'm not familiar with the nature of the foam used for slab jacking. Is it very hard (dense)?

@isherwood   Ads I saw for jacking up of slabs said they used bentonite(or similar) for injection.  This was years ago, so might use different stuff now.

I know it's done with mineral or cement products also, but this question specifically mentions foam.

@isherwood I've not been able to pull out any foam from the pipe using a basic drain auger from roughly 3ft away. The same product appears to have been used under the concrete driveway as well. Based on that I'd judge the foam as rather dense.

A pressure washer should cut through many kinds of foam especially if you use a 0° turbo nozzle. This is a nozzle that shoots a very narrow stream of water while oscillating in a circular pattern. The chance of success increases with PSI of the pressure washer -- a gas-powered washer will be more likely to eat through the foam than a small electric washer will be.
However, a consumer pressure washer is quite unlikely to cut through the wall of a corrugated HDPE drain pipe. (Pressure washers/pumps of similar spec are used in hydroexcavation, which is an industry-standard practice for uncovering buried utilities without risking damage to them!)
It should be easy enough to stay clear of the to-be-abandoned pipe while installing a new pipe simply by staying far enough to the side of the old one. There could be an issue of your tunnel running into the slab-jacking foam material though. Clearly the foam is going to be filling voids directly below the slab -- and your drain pipe is likely to be shallow, occupying that same vertical region. All you can do is try though.
What have you tried so far for clearing the foam blockage from the existing pipe? If the pipe is nearly straight, and assuming that it is not collapsed, you might be able to clear or at least penetrate the foam blockage from within it by mechanical means. The latter two in this list would be capable of damaging the existing pipe, but using them to intentionally damage or remove portions of it would be arduous.

pressure washer inserted from either or both ends
a long drill bit ("bellhanger" or "flex auger" drill or similar, especially in combination with something homemade functionally similar to the Rack-A-Tiers Bumper Ball product)
a valve key (or "curb key") driven in with a hammer, then twisted, might take little bites out of the foam


From the inlet side of the pipe a household style drain cleaning auger has not been able to make any progress. There is a 90-degree bend after the inlet and I'm not able to get my 36" installer bit to bend that far or to reach the foam.
The existing outlet is seemingly buried and its location is not known. My assumption is that it would turn to the rear of the house shortly after passing under the concrete sidewalk due to a property line not far from the sidewalk, and would potentially join with another underground  drain near the back of the house.
